# Why aren't transformers imported in Python?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to import transformers in jupyter notebook but I get the following error. What is the reason for this error? My Python version is 3.8

ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeAlias' from 'typing_extensions'

I also updated the typing-extensions library version, but the problem was not resolved

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The shortest code necessary to replicate your problem and the ***full*** error traceback

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
pip install typing-extensions --upgrade
```

Comment: OP says, "I also updated the typing-extensions library version, but the problem was not resolved"

Comment: While the OP did say "*I also updated the typing-extensions library version*", it wasn't clear how exactly they did it, and to which version it was upgraded to.

Comment: Upgrading to `typing-extensions` 4.7.1 makes it work with Python 3.8. For my use case, I got away with installing it with `pip install typing-extensions --upgrade --user`, which has the benefit of not having to use sudo on Linux and endangering system components.
When updating a pip package does not have results, you may need to check if your pip and your python match up. When in doubt, check the installed version using python's built-in pip using `python3 -m pip list|grep typing-extensions` (substitute `python3` with the interpreter you use to start your script if needed)

Answer (score 1):

TypeAlias is available from python version 3.10.
You should upgrade your python version to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the probelm is the version of datasets package:
pip install datasets==1.15

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).